# WebDAV: can a client modify the mtime of a file?

Tags: properties, webdav

Is a WebDAV client, per RFC, able to update the modification-date timestamp of a file. WebDAV lists this as the "getlastmodified" property.
Being able to do a utime() on files is quite important when moving files as I regard mtime as essential file metadata. But for example doing a propset with cadaver (which I regard as a kind of reference implementation of WebDAV) it constantly maps the getlastmodifed property into its own namespace, thus directing the call away from the actual on-disk file timestamo which could be updated via utime...

Example PROPPATCH request sent by cadaver:

```
<D:propertyupdate xmlns:D="DAV:">
  <D:set>
   <D:prop>
    <DAV:getlastmodified xmlns="http://webdav.org/cadaver/custom-properties/">Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT</DAV:getlastmodified>
   </D:prop>
 </D:set>
</D:propertyupdate>
```

I've got a server running which would update the getlastmodifed property, if only it wasn't mapped into a different namespace...

Comment: The example looks fishy; it seems to be not wellformed (the prefix "DAV" doesn't seem to be declared).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DAV:getlastmodified` property is read only on usual WebDAV servers. It is however modified if you `PUT` or `POST` a file. If you want to modify it later, implementing something in the server like support for a `PROPSET` to `lastmodified` (mind the missing get) which does the `utime()` call might be an option.

For example the ownCloud WebDAV server does it that way.

Comment: Note that this is actually a bad idea. If other clients use If-Modified-Since to find out if the file changed, this may no longer work. It's better to supply an alternative property.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have answered your own question:

If you had a client that sent a PROPPATCH with the correct namespace then you wouldn't have this issue. Maybe try patching cadaver, or at least work out if the DAV client you are going to use exhibits this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I use mydav.php as webdav server, and webdrive as webdav client(in settings: Set files modified time after upload to preserve date/time).

mydav.php:

https://code.google.com/p/mydav/

webdrive:

http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/index.html